# Multiple webservice call using Parallel.Foreach

Tags: c#, web-services, parallel-processing, .net-3.5

I need to process multiple data retrieved from a webservice that only get me single info, like the example below:

```
List<string> products = GetAllProducts();
List<ProductInfo> productsInfo = new List<ProductInfo>();

using (var channel = GetClientChannel<IService>("http://localhost:51383/Service/Service.svc"))
{
    Parallel.ForEach(products, product =>
    {
        Request myRequest = new Request();
        Response myResponse = null;
        try
        {
            myRequest.ID = product;
            myResponse = channel.GetProductInfo(myRequest);
            productsInfo.Add(myResponse.Info);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            // Continue build ProductInfo list
        }
    });
}

DoSomething(productsInfo);
```

What's the best approach for something like this?
Would the parallel for each improve the performance or it will not be affected since i'm calling the service in the same host/port?

Answer (score 1):

If you service is not concurrent, I think doing the parallel for each will not make much difference since calls to the service will only be handled one at a time. What you need to do is either make your service [Concurrent](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.servicebehaviorattribute.concurrencymode%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) by using something like:

```
[ServiceBehavior(ConcurrencyMode = ConcurrencyMode.Multiple)]
class MyService : IMyService
```

or change the [InstanceContext](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.instancecontext%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) mode in the service behavior so that each call to the service creates a new process on the server where the service is hosted, something like

```
[ServiceBehavior(InstanceContextMode=InstanceContextMode.PerCall)]
class MyService : IMyService
```

If you do any of these, make sure you take care of issues related to threading. More about these attributes is explained in [WCF Concurrency tutorial](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/89858/WCF-Concurrency-Single-Multiple-and-Reentrant-and)